# Getting this import error. Also, suggest any other method, to continue to next iteration if time taken is more than a certain value

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Aisitaisi/All_about_Contest/raw.py", line 1, in <module>
    from interruptingcow import timeout
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\interruptingcow\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from contextlib import GeneratorContextManager
ImportError: cannot import name 'GeneratorContextManager'
```

---

```
from interruptingcow import timeout
import time
@timeout(.5)
def foo():
    with timeout(.3):
        # some expensive operation
        pass``
```

Comment: There's no `contextlib.GeneratorContextManager`, and nothing can be done about it.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0):

The `interruptingcow` module is relying on undocumented implementation details of the `contextlib` module, specifically Python 2's undocumented `contextlib.GeneratorContextManager`. These implementation details have changed in the Python version you are running. There's a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/evzijst/interruptingcow/pull-requests/2/add-python-3-support/diff) that would fix this, but it hasn't been merged, and development activity on the module seems dead.

Stop trying to use `interruptingcow`.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in latest version, install 0.8